# Handle void method as object's property in React, redux, typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Below are the details. I am a little confused on how to test my file with an object with function that return void.

```
type Pros={
 studentid: StudentId
 pageId?: PageID
 closeForm: () => void 
}
```

For a unit test, how should I send this?

```
const testPros={
 studentid: "123"
 pageId: "123"
 closeForm: null //I am confused here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that doesn't have implicit return nor has the `return` keyword anywhere. (Don't use `return;` or `return undefined;`.) You should also use `pageId`, not `padeId`, and each key-value pair should be separated with a comma.

```
const testPros = {
  studentid:"123",
  pageId:"123",
  closeForm() {
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
const testPros= {
  studentid: "123",
  pageId: "123",
  closeForm: () => {},
}
```

the type `() => void` means the `closeForm` accepts a function that has no parameters and does not have a return value.

You could also have a function like:

```
const closeFormHandler = () => {
  // Do something here without a return statement
}

const testPros= {
  studentid: "123",
  pageId: "123",
  closeForm: closeFormHandler,
}
```